# I'm using Brother DCP 7025 printer/scanner, but I cannot use the scanner

Tags: scanner

Where will I find a suitable driver, and how can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

You can (apparently) download .deb files from the brother support website.  You will be looking for a 'brscan2' model, and your particular device is listed on [their webpage](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html)

On that same webpage is a link to the [scanner installation instructions](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on) which seem to indicate that the software will work with Ubuntu 8.04 and above...